# PYTHONPATH and PATH system variables

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis

I am working with quantum gis 1.7.2.During installation it creates python25 folder. 
I am working with  python2.6 for python plugins for QGIS.
i set system variable as:

```
PATH :=C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis
     C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin 
PYTHONPATH:=C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python;
```

**ErrorMessage**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\rt_sql_layer_working\DlgQueryBuilder.py", line 30, in <module>
from qgis.core import *
```

**ImportError**: `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

is this because of version mismatch  or paths are wrong??

Comment: Have you tried installing Python 2.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the python in python25 folder and at the prompt do

```
   from qgis.core import *
```

If this is working fine, perhaps  there are additional libraries provided with this python25 which are not present in 2.6.

You might need to copy these dll's to your python2.6 installation

Comment: did you try running from python25 ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd just want your PATH to be something like c:\PYTHON26 or c:\PYTHON25 not the one you've specified:

C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin